# Вывод даты обновления статьи в title wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет.
есть сайт на wordpress. стоит плагин The SEO Framework

Как вывести в тайтл статьи, дату обновления статьи?
Например сейчас тайтл у статьи: Приобретение электронного ОСАГО в 2020 году
надо добавить: Приобретение электронного ОСАГО в 2020 году - Обновлено 07.06.2020 (текущая дата)

Только не путайте заголовок статьи с тайтлом который в шапке сайта выводится в теге title

нужно именно в этот тег добавить дату последнего обновления статьи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте фильтр `the_seo_framework_title_from_custom_field`.
В моем примере добавляется текст к тайтлу всех постов и страниц:

```php
/**
 * Добавить суффикс к title для всех постов и страниц, если заполнено поле Meta Title
 */
add_filter( 'the_seo_framework_title_from_custom_field', function( $title, $args ) {
    if ( !empty($title) && ( is_single() || is_page() ) ) {
        $title .= ' - Обновлено ' . get_the_modified_date('d.m.Y', get_the_ID());
    }

    return $title;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Про другие фильтры The SEO Framework читайте: https://theseoframework.com/docs/api/filters/

Comment: is_single() || is_page() видимо нужно заменить на чтото другое. потому что не работает. как понять на что заменить?

Comment: Нет, код тестировал на чистом сайте, работает правильно

Comment: у меня не работает(( может в настройках плагина нужно чтото сделать..

Comment: Может у вас тайтл явно прописан в настройках плагина (см. поле Meta Title) на странице? Если так, то нужно это убрать, тогда код будет работать.

Comment: так на каждой странице статей, есть настройка для тайтла. и туда вводится тайтл который нужен. нужно чтобы и тайтл туда вводился и плюс дата обновления появлялась

Comment: Обновил ответ, проверьте, должно работать так, как вы хотите.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'the_seo_framework_title_from_generation', 'my_the_seo_framework_title_from_generation' );
function my_the_seo_framework_title_from_generation( $title ) {
    if ( is_singular() ) {
        $title .= ' - Обновлено ' . get_the_modified_date( 'd.m.Y' );
    }

    return $title;
}
```

Подробнее про фильтры The SEO Framefork: https://theseoframework.com/docs/api/filters/

Подробнее про функцию: https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_the_modified_date

Comment: Это же в function.php нужно добавить? чтото ничего не поменялось почемуто

Comment: Добавить в functions.php. Проверку is_singular замените на свою

Comment: не работает( может в настройках плагина нужно чтото сделать